# Model failed to load at Cloud ML Engine but works locally

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I trained and exported a model using SavedModel and, as suggested at [Online Predict](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/online-predict), I tested it locally and worked just fine.

When I requested for predictions I didn't worked out,for both online and batch predictions. For online prediction I got:

```
jsonPayload: {
  @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.ml.v1.PredictionLogEntry"    
  message:  "{"error": "Prediction failed: Exception during model execution: 
  AbortionError(code=StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, 
    details=\"Attempting to use uninitialized value bout/weight\n\t 
      [[Node: bout/weight/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, 
      _class=[\"loc:@bout/weight\"], 
      _output_shapes=[[1,2]], 
      _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0\"](bout/weight)]]
  \")"}"    
  numInstances:  "1"
```

and for batch prediction:

```
 16:21:35.855
PermanentException: Failed to load the model due to bad model data. [while running 'BATCH_PREDICTION/Prediction/ParDo(PredictionDoFn)/Do']


{
 insertId: "xunb3og1phwaag"  
 logName: "projects/toycloudml/logs/ml.googleapis.com%2Fdnn_test3"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2017-07-11T19:21:35.855457468Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id: "dnn_test3"    
   project_id: "toycloudml"    
   task_name: "service"    
  }
  type: "ml_job"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "PermanentException: Failed to load the model due to bad model data. [while running 'BATCH_PREDICTION/Prediction/ParDo(PredictionDoFn)/Do']
"  
 timestamp: "2017-07-11T19:21:35.855457468Z"  
}
```

I created my model using `gcloud ml-engine models create $MODEL_NAME --regions=$REGION --enable-logging`,
the version with `gcloud ml-engine versions create v1 --model $MODEL_NAME --origin $MODEL_BINARIES --runtime-version 1.2`
and requested batch predictions with `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit prediction $JOB_NAME --model $MODEL_NAME --version v1 --data-format TEXT --region $REGION --input-paths $INPUT_PATHS --output-path $OUTPUT_PATH`

I can't figure out why this is happening since every worked just fine with local prediction. Did I missed something?

Comment: To test things out locally are you using `gcloud ml-engine local predict`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ```gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=$MODEL_DIR --json-instances=$INPUT_DATA_FILE```

Comment: At first glance, this seems like it might be a bug. We can help investigate if you are willing to send your project/model/version name to a (private) mailing list cloudml-feedback@google.com.

Comment: Can you share the complete log entry for batch prediction?

Comment: @rhaertel80 I sent the info as requested

Comment: @yxshi I edited the question with the batch prediction log